Delete rows based on a condition of another column
here is an image of it
I am trying to work in SQL server just its easier to show it in Excel.
I have two columns: cardnumber and comment.
If one cardnumber exists twice in my database and it has a row with a comment "corrected" and also exists with the comment "closed" then I need to delete the line with the comment "corrected".
I have no idea how to manage it, I tried with exists but it does not work.
Thank you all.
I tried
SELECT 
* 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT CARDNUMBER, COMMENT FROM TABLE1 WHERE COMMENT IN ('CORRECTED', 'CLOSED')

But it does not work.

Mysql is not SQL server please correct your tags

Please do not use images use formatted text

Something like: select * from table1 t1 where comment = 'corrected' and exists(select 1 from table1 t2 where t2.CardN = t.CardN and t2.comment = 'closed') although this doesn't check that table has two rows exactly

A [mcve] is supposed to include the expected result too.

Here is one approach using a deletable CTE:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN comment = 'closed' THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY cardnumber) AS closed_cnt
    FROM Table1
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE comment = 'corrected' AND closed_cnt > 0;

